# Google Analytics for Firebase does not capture CFBundleShortVersionString for IOS or VersionNumber for Anrdoid

Tags: xamarin, firebase-analytics

I am trying to implement Google Analytics for Firebase in our XAMARIN code and realized that the automatic captured property AppVersion does not have the code version in order word CFBundleShortVersionString  for IOS and VersionNumber for Android.

The version I am expecting it to capture is EX 4.3.53 where as it is only caturing 4.3. Is there a way I can send the CFBundleShortVersionString and VersionName with the APPVersion parameter automatically?

Or I have to send a new custom parameter with this info?

Comment: Please share the code where you are sharing the version number to analytics, so we can help you fix that

Comment: App Version is a user property which is automatically getting captured by Google fire base. We are not sending any value.

Comment: Firebase by default does not have any way of send the Short version if you intend to do that you would want to send it as a custom parameter.

Comment: Is there a way we tell firebase to capture this value? Wondering by adding a custom property is really helpful as default filters on App Versions will have major version and minor version. I tried to Put a custom value (ex: 4.4.3 (12) ) in the App versions field and in the stream view it showed me 4.4.